# Apache Spark or Flink: Sharing sources across processes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-flink, streaming

I have a use case for a large-ish streaming application and am tasked with finding a suitable technology to implement it.

I need to build an "alerting" application over streamed events where the alerting condition will be defined by the end user (through a proprietary DSL).

My events come through Kafka, there is about 20-ish topics to listen to. Some topics have up to a thousand msg/s, some a lot less. In total, a few thousands msg/s to evaluate against my alert conditions.

I can expect up to 10,000 alert conditions to have to be evaluated concurrently. These are long running queries (they will trigger alerts as long as the user keep the condition active).

The alert conditions are stateless (no aggregation, either over several "time series" or over time). A single event can potentially match over several alert conditions. The solution *might* evolve later to provide room for aggregation (probably over a single time series, but over time - max(), min(), average() sort of aggregation). The evaluation of the conditions must be *near real-time* (in the order of a few seconds max). If we ever support aggregation the conditions need to maintain a sliding window with the aggregate.

Obviously, I cannot have each Flink Job or Spark application reading and processing events independently. It would blow the I/O on my Kafka cluster. I need some logic of the type "Read-once Process-Many".

I am new to those technologies (Spark & Flink). Reading the documentation, it is not clear to me if any of those stacks provide some primitives to allow me the concept of read-once process-many.

Does any of you have an idea on how such a use case might be implemented?

Kindest thanks in advance

Comment: I'd suggest using Kafka Connect to send to InfluxDB https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.7/monitor-alert/

Comment: Sadly this won't fit the bill. We need near real-time alerting. We already have a timeseries database and running periodic queries to that purpose. But for the new feature, this is not good enough anymore. I will edit the post to specify that the evaluation must be near real time

Comment: If you want immediate triggers, then embed some HTTP client that sends events to external systems like PagerDuty/Slack/Email, etc